# fabric.js on node.js loadFromDatalessJSON moves objects when in a group

Tags: node.js, fabricjs

I am serializing a canvas on the client, and post it to a node.js server (ubuntu 14.10, with node.js version v0.10.34 and fabric 1.4.13).
On the client canvas, objects are in a group.
The problem is, the objects are moved when de-serialized on the server.
Client code:

```
    $(function(){
    fc= new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
    fc.setBackgroundColor('white');

    group = new fabric.Group([], {  hasControls:false, hasBorders:true, top:-fc.getHeight(), left:-fc.getWidth(), width:2*fc.getWidth(), height:2*fc.getHeight(), hoverCursor:'default' });
    fc.add(group);

    // create a rectangle object
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 150,
      top: 100,
      fill: 'red',
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    });

    // "add" rectangle onto canvas
    group.add(rect);

    var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 100,
      top: 150,
      fill: 'blue',
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    });
    group.add(rect2);

    fc.renderAll();

    $.post( window.location.origin+':8124/', {
            width: group.getWidth(),
            height: group.getHeight(),
            data: encodeURI(JSON.stringify(fc.toDatalessJSON()))
            }, function( data ) {}
    );

});
```

Server code:

```
var fabric = require('fabric').fabric;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var    PORT = 8124;

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb'}) );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true,
    limit: '50mb'
  })); 

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('Post received');
    if (req.body) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' });

        var w=parseInt(req.body.width);
        var h=parseInt(req.body.height);
        var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(w, h);
        console.log(req.body.data);

        out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/mindmap.png');

        canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(decodeURI(req.body.data), function() {
                canvas.renderAll();

                console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON()));
                var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
                stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
                        out.write(chunk);
                        console.log('writing chunk');
                });
                stream.on('end', function() {
                        out.end();                      
                });
        });
    }
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

The console.log statement shows that the two rects are created (left:15, top-35) and (left:-35, top:15) respectively.
On the client, top/left object properties are relative to center of the group.
This is why I create the group with -fc.getWidth and-fc.getHeight left and top respectively. This works fine on the client.
Maybe this is not the case on the server?

EDIT: this seems to be an issue with loadFromDatalessJSON, at least on node.
Running the following code on the node server shows that top/left properties of the rectangles are wrong after serializing the first canvas and deserializing into the second one:

```
var fabric = require('fabric').fabric;
var fs = require('fs');


var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(200, 200);
canvas.setBackgroundColor('white');

var out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/mindmap.png');

var group = new fabric.Group([], { top:-200, left:-200, width:400, height:400});
canvas.add(group);

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left:150,
            top:100,
            fill:'red',
            width:20,
            height:20
});
group.add(rect);

var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
            left:100,
            top:150,
            fill:'blue',
            width:20,
            height:20
});
group.add(rect2);

canvas.renderAll();
console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON()));

var canvas2 = fabric.createCanvasForNode(200, 200);
canvas2.loadFromDatalessJSON(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
canvas2.renderAll();

var stream = canvas2.createPNGStream();
stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        out.write(chunk);
        console.log('writing chunk');
});
stream.on('end', function() {
        out.end();                      
        console.log('png image generated');
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas2.toDatalessJSON()));
```

Next step is to run similar code on the client and see if the problem exists as well.

EDIT2: the same problem occurs on the client, and with toJSON as well instead of toDatalessJSON. Can someone help? Is this a known issue with groups serialization/deserialization? Is there a workaround?

Thanks

After searching for similar issues, it looks like this is very similar to [#1159] [https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1159]

But this issue is supposed to be fixed, and I don't have any transform on my canvas ...

Comment: I am having the same problem! JSON.stringify(canvas) causes my group of objects to jump around!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed it by installing the latest version from the github releases section: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/releases

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I installed the latest version (1.4.13) and I am still having the same problem (on the client, I have not yet tried on the server).
Any other idea?